# What is the purpose of ears in Diablo II

Tags: diablo-ii

This is something that has always puzzled me since the release of diablo 2.  What is the purpose of collecting ears?  I know that if I kill someone in PvP I get an ear with their name attached to it.  Do these offer any value or is it just a "treasure"?

Comment: Good to see people Still Play Diablo 2 AND PVP on this Awesome game by 2011. I also play it, and i can garantee is not because of the graphics. This game is awesome

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ears are just a "trophy" to show that you killed someone. Ears can be sold for 1 gold, but apart from that, they are useless.

Answer (score 6):

No, they don't have any value other than you can show off who you have killed in PvP. They are just a trophy for Player kills.

Answer (score 5):

They have more of a relevance in hardcore to show that you killed OR died in pvp combat. Some players in the PvP community hold them ransom over other combatants.

Answer (score 1):

On the PS4, there’s an achievement for collecting 20 player ears.